# How to create GitHub portfolio from scratch?

Tags: file, github, repository, project

I want to know how to create a GitHub portfolio link where I can showcase my projects and keep in resume.
I went to GitHub and created a repository with name My-Portfolio.
I created one folder on desktop and I kept my first project (TypingSpeed) files (html,css, JavaScript) but I am unable to open the html and JavaScript files even after doing extract all.
And I want to know:
After uploading the files in GitHub, what is the further process?
How to unzip the files in a folder?
How can I add more than one projects?
After adding projects what should I do?
How to create a single link for all this projects?
Explain in detail how my portfolio should be?

I went to GitHub and created a repository with name My-Portfolio.
I created one folder on desktop and I kept my first project (TypingSpeed) files (html,css, JavaScript) but I am unable to open the html and JavaScript files even after doing extract all.
What I expected is my files should open and I should drop or upload the files in GitHub.
But my hunk and JavaScript files did not open.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.